# What is git-rerere and how does it work?

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, git-rerere

As I understood, it is useful for the synchronization of projects through the saving of conflict resolution information, but it is not entirely clear to me how to use and configure it.

I want to configure for my continuous integration (CI) environment. Is it recommended do this?

Please don't mark a duplicate with this other question: [Are there any downsides to enabling git rerere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519244/are-there-any-downsides-to-enabling-git-rerere). Because my doubt isn't related to ***"So is there any downside to enabling rerere?. What potential problems can it cause that would not otherwise occur?"***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any downsides to enabling git rerere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519244/are-there-any-downsides-to-enabling-git-rerere)

Answer (score 84):

#### What is `git rerere`?

As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) notes, `rerere` stands for *re*use *re*corded *re*solution.

That doesn't really explain *what it is*, though.  It's worth adding first, here, that `git rerere` itself—the command—is not something you have to run.  It has just six subcommands: `clear`, `forget`, `diff`, `status`, `remaining`, and `gc`.  None of these record or reuse a resolution—in fact, `git rerere clear` and `git rerere forget <path>` just *discard* some recorded resolutions.  The `gc` command is similar, but refers to ones that are old, rather than current ones.

Most of the work happens from the *setting* of `rerere.enabled` (which makes Git run `git rerere`, with no subcommand, for you, at the appropriate times).  You can run `git rerere` with no subcommands yourself, but this doesn't really do anything important since Git will do that on its own.

#### `git config rerere.enabled true`

Once you have set `rerere.enabled`, when Git does a merge—any merge, including those from `git am` and `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` and so on, not just those from `git merge` itself—and hits a conflict, Git will:

2. record (once the merge-as-a-verb hits them) the conflicting diff hunks;
3. wait for you to resolve them manually;
4. record (at `git commit` time) what you did to resolve them.

There's a step missing here, which is why this is numbered starting at 2.  Step 1 is:

1. check for previous recorded resolutions for these conflicts: if they exist, use them to resolve those conflicts *automatically*.

If the recorded resolutions completely resolve the conflicts, steps 2-4 become redundant.  Git may still run them all (I'm not sure that it does) to update the timestamps on the recorded resolutions.

#### Summary

Once you set `rerere.enabled`, it's the act of merging itself that both creates the conflicts *and* (because it automatically runs `git rerere` with no arguments) records them and then tries to re-use any existing recorded resolutions.  It's the act of committing itself that records the final resolutions (because Git automatically runs `git rerere` again for you).  So it is all automatic—you just need to make sure, by running your own `git diff` commands, that your previous re-used resolutions are correct.  If not, just fix them files, add, and commit as usual, and Git will replace the recorded resolutions with the new ones.

Note that you must still `git add` and `git commit`!  You should always *inspect the merge results* (and/or run tests)—though you should do this always, regardless of your `rerere.enabled` setting.

As [VonC points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work/49501436?noredirect=1#comment86015280_49501436), if you have existing merge conflict resolutions you did not record earlier, you can "train" the rerere database on those resolutions.  [There is a contributed script in the Git source to do this; it's also available on-line.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664714/1256452)

Comment: "Once you set `rerere.enabled`"... well, yes, but don't forget you can train rerere on *past* conflict resolutions done when it was *not* yet enable. Either manually (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155237/6309) or through  the `contrib/rerere-train.sh` script (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664714/6309)

Comment: Aha, the `train` script is the one I always wanted to have.

Comment: Thank you for "record (**at git commit time**) what you did to resolve them." The `git help rerere` page isn't clear about when that happens.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the rerere train script to work correctly. It just keeps asking me for my pin to sign what I believe is each and every commit available in the repo. This isn't really workable. I also don't see why it would need to do this as the commits shouldn't change here.

Comment: @MartijnOtto the train script re-performs each merge, committing (then throwing away) the result. If you've set Git to demand GPG signatures on each commit, you'll have to sign all these new merge commits. The script could stand to disable signing while it does this training. You might submit that as a fix to either the Git mailing list, or the author of the script.

Comment: will my resolutions get recorded if I enable rerere after running `git merge` but before `git add & git commit`?

Comment: @zaabson: no: the initial inputs need to be recorded and that happens at the time `git merge` stops with a conflict. You can abort the merge (`git merge --abort`) and then start it over; now that `rerere` is enabled, the *new* merge will stop with the same conflict(s) and this time, it will record them. If you've done a bunch of work to resolve them, you might want to save that work before you `git merge --abort`, of course. (I should also add that perhaps running `git rerere` with no arguments would suffice. I haven't tested this!)

Answer (score 10):

It makes no sense to enable `rerere` for your CI environment, because your CI environment should never be resolving merge conflicts in the first place. Why do you think you would want it there?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot seem to get the rerere train script to work correctly. It just keeps asking me for my pin to sign what I believe is each and every commit available in the repo.

It should ask you *less* with git 2.38 (Q3 2022): "`rerere-train`" script (in `contrib/`) used to honor `commit.gpgSign` while recreating the throw-away merges. This has been fixed.

See [commit cc391fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc391fc886639fb589b4e8da6a4e1a98d3ee07ab) (20 Jul 2022) by [Celeste Liu (`CoelacanthusHex`)](https://github.com/CoelacanthusHex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f0f9a03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0f9a033ed3c053b6cff33fd0aed59aed1e8dc00), 01 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`contrib/rerere-train`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc391fc886639fb589b4e8da6a4e1a98d3ee07ab): avoid useless gpg sign in training
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Celeste Liu</sup>

> Users may have configured "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cc391fc886639fb589b4e8da6a4e1a98d3ee07ab/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> to always require GPG signing the resulting commits.
> We are not running "`git merge`" to re-create merge commits, but merely to replay merge conflicts, and we will immediately discard the resulting commits; there is no point in signing them.
>
> Override such configuration that forces useless signing from the command line with the "`--no-gpg-sign`" option.