# Combine all commits into one before rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I have a local / remote branchA that I am only working on. BranchA was created from develop branch. I have made somewhere like a dozen commits to it. Now I am at a stage where I want to pull all the changes from develop that were made in the meantime, so that BranchA is containing all the latest changes from develop, so I can test it.

I have tried to rebase develop onto BranchA, but it is a bit difficult to resolve conflicts. What happens is that there is a FileA that was changed in developer branch, but I have also changed this file in lot of my commits (lets say 8). So it seems that git is asking me to resolve conflict for this file 8 times, while I would like it to ask me only for latest version.

So, what are my options here? Should I merge all my 12 commits into 1, and then try to rebase? How would I correctly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to rebase develop onto BranchA

No: you need to rebase your branch onto the common branch develop

```
git checkout BranchA
git rebase develop
```

If a similar merge conflict appears many time, [`git rerere` can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501436/6309).

Another approach would be simply to merge `develop` into `BranchA`.

> The point is that I want to add the change in FileA from new develop commit, to latest version for FileA from my BranchA.

For a given file, you can simply checkout it once the rebase is blocked by a conflict:

```
 git checkout develop -- FileA
 git rebase --continue
```

That way, the resolution is very quick (since you override FileA with the one from the `develop` branch)

Comment: That is what I did, sorry for wrong expression. The point is that I want to add the change in FileA from new develop commit, to latest version for FileA from my BranchA. I do not want to resolve conflicts for each commit to this file that I made in BranchA, only between 1st and last. Will merge action make changes to develop branch too? Or can I safely say that any git action will make changes only on the ckecedout branch?

Comment: @Goran I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the best course of action here is (generally that's fairly preference/policy driven), but if you want to do a rebase and squash all the commits together into one, you can do:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i BranchA
```

which will open up an editor with a line for each commit on `develop` that doesn't exist in `BranchA`.

There are instructions in this editor that outline what you can do, but in this case you can:

- leave the topmost (first) commit action as `pick`
- change all the other commit actions to `squash` or `fixup`

The difference between `squash` and `fixup` is that squash will concatenate all the commit messages of the squashed commits together and allow you to edit this commit message, whereas `fixup` will just use the commit message of the commit that the others are "fixed-up" onto, without allowing you to edit it.

My preference is generally to use `squash` to keep at least some semblance of the commit history, but it all depends on how polished my branch has been up till that point.