# Dealing with merge conflicts in future updates

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Looking for a best practice here. Our process is that we create a new branch from master

```
master --> myBranch
```

make our updates, then push to dev

```
myBranch --> dev
```

Obviously, sometimes we have merge conflicts on dev. In that situation, we we checkout our branch via:

```
git fetch origin myBranch
git checkout dev
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

we then resolve our conflicts and...

```
git push origin HEAD
```

My understanding of the above is that I'm merging myBranch into dev manually, and then pushing my local dev changes to remote.

That's usually the end of it.

But now I need to make further updates to myBranch and push to dev and that's where I'm stumped. Won't I now (likely) get the same conflicts as before? What's the best practice here? Should I be doing a `git pull origin dev` to update my own branch to match dev?

Comment: If you are merging your changes to dev, why not also branch from dev?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49500943/354577) helps.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Use this sequence to pull the remote data and update your branches:

```
git checkout myBranch
git pull

git checkout dev
git pull

git merge myBranch
... resolve conflicts ...
git push HEAD
```

There's a chance that **similar** conflicts will happen again in future if `myBranch` will edit the same parts of files again. The conflicts, though, will never be the exactly the same. 
If you still want to avoid that - you need to push your merge commit to `myBranch` (but note that it will bring all `dev` changes to `myBranch`):

```
git checkout myBranch
git merge dev
... this is a Fast-Forward merge ...
git push HEAD
```

## Long answer

Your understanding is right:

> ... I'm merging myBranch into dev manually, and then pushing my local dev changes to remote.

and this is almost correct too:

> Should I be doing a `git pull origin dev` to update my own branch to match dev?

So, yes - the current approach indeed merges `myBranch` into `dev` manually, and then `dev` is pushed to the remote repository. And yes - it's better to update your local `dev` first.

There are a couple of assumptions that are not that correct, and it's great that you have created an SO question to verify them.

**First of all** - `git pull origin dev` is not a universally right command to update your local branch `dev`. What it does is pulling the remote `dev`changes, but it updates your local `dev` branch only if you're on it already. Seems like you're not - because in the provided example you check that branch out before merging FETCH_HEAD. So the suggestion is either to check out the branch before pulling its changes:

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev

git fetch origin myBranch
git merge FETCH_HEAD

git push HEAD
```

or use a different command to both get the changes and update your local branch (you must not be on that branch currently):

```
git fetch origin dev:dev
git checkout dev

git fetch origin myBranch
git merge FETCH_HEAD

git push HEAD
```

But probably more simple is just to pull all the updates, and then merge the branches you need:

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git merge origin/myBranch

git push HEAD
```

However all the code snippets above leave your local `myBranch` not updated with the changes done in remote repository, which is inconvenient for further work. So the best practice is to update both local branches before merging them:

```
git checkout myBranch
git pull

git checkout dev
git pull

git merge myBranch
git push HEAD
```

**Second:**

> Should I be doing a `git pull origin dev` to update my own branch to match dev?

This is needed not just for merging, but for your ability to push changes back. If you won't update your local `dev`, while remote has some changes in `dev`, then you literally won't be able to push your merge commit to the remote repository, and you will need to resolve even more conflicts first.

**Third:**

> I need to make further updates to myBranch ... Won't I now (likely) get the same conflicts as before?

This is possible, though those won't be exactly same conflicts. To get them `myBranch` will need to modify the parts of code that you changed in `dev` (including in that merge commit). Modifying code in other files or even in other parts of the same file won't produce the conflicts. To avoid the conflicts you'd better sync `myBranch` with `dev` as well (if you're ok to see other `dev` changes getting to `myBranch`):

```
... do all the pull-merge-push stuff as suggested above ...

git checkout myBranch
git merge dev
... this is a Fast-Forward merge ...
git push HEAD
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! That last bit answer the big question I had...wanting to update my local MyBranch to match Dev to avoid further conflicts with future merge requests.