# How can I merge two lines from one revision and a third from the other in vimdiff?

Tags: vim, merge, vimdiff

I am merging two git branches together. I am using vimdiff to do this, so there are three vim panes shown in my terminal.

This same conflict arises hundreds of times in my merge:
[image: vimdiff example]

Every time I come across it, I want to do the same thing: keep the top two lines from HEAD (pink) and the bottom line from OTHER (blue).

At the moment I am typing:
    diffg 3
To accept blue's changes, then going into insert mode and changing the etc's to var's manually.

I feel like there must be a quicker way to keep the top two lines from pink and the third line from blue every time. Is there? This would save me a lot of typing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the conflict is always the same, perhaps, you can use `git rerere` ([What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work)).

If it is not a conflict occurring over different conflicts (like if the conflict is present many times in the file), you can make a macro:

```
qq
```

Search for the conflict:

```
/<<<<<<<
```

Delete the line:

```
dd
```

Find the middle of the conflict:

```
/=======
```

Go in line visual mode:

```
V
```

Find the line just before the last blue line you want to keep:

```
/plan-path
```

Delete all that:

```
d
```

Find the end of the conflict:

```
/>>>>>>>
```

Delete it

```
dd
```

Finally, stop the macro:

```
q
```

Once you made the macro, count the number of occurrences of the conflict:

```
:%s/<<<<<<<//n
```

Execute the macro as many times:

```
42@q
```

If you have other types of conflicts, you can adapt the macro to your needs.

Comment: Your macro deletes all of the « blue » diff... OP wants to keep 3rd line