# Git merge conflict upon rebasing adjacent deletion and insertion?

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I am in the process of cleaning up a series of commits for pushing to the master branch.

In the process I am running into a recurring type of merge conflict, that appears when a deletion and an insertion are adjacent to each other.

Is there same way to handle such cases automatically, without error-prone manual conflict resolution?

## Example

Let’s say I have the following sequence of commits:

```
           (master)                      (devel, HEAD)
History    A ------------- B ----------- C

File State : This          : This        : This
           :   is          :   is        :   is
           :   some        :   some      :   some
           :   versioned   :   official  :   official
           :   document.   :   versioned :   document.
           :               :   document. :

Diff       :               :   some      :   official
           :               :+  official  :-  versioned
           :               :   document. :   document.
```

Now, as part of the clean-up, I need to change the order of the insertion and deletion. The target is the following:

```
           (master)                      (devel, HEAD)
History    A ------------- B’ ---------- C’

File State : This          : This        : This
           :   is          :   is        :   is
           :   some        :   some      :   some
           :   versioned   :   document. :   official
           :   document.   :             :   document.

Diff       :               :   some      :   some
           :               :-  versioned :+  official
           :               :   document. :   document.
```

I am trying to achieve this by

```
>> git checkout devel
>> git rebase -i master
```

with the rebase-todo set to

```
pick C
pick B
```

After `pick C` this gives a merge conflict.

```
@@@ -1,5 -1,5 +1,9 @@@
  This
    is
    some
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +  versioned
++=======
+   official
++>>>>>>> 9a2f008... Remove word 'versioned'
    document
```

If I resolve the conflict by hand. After `pick B`, another conflict occurs:

```
@@@ -1,4 -1,6 +1,9 @@@
  This
    is
    some
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++=======
+   official
+   versioned
++>>>>>>> 6a39609... Add word 'official'
    document
```

In this simple example, it is viable, because I can remember for each step the exact state I want. In real-world applications, this is by far not that easy, and there is a high chance of mixing things up.

Is there some better way to do this?

## Real world use-case

While working on a ticket, I created a mixture of maintenance changes, addition of debug statements, and changes actually fixing the ticket. In order to clean up the resulting mess, I did

```
git reset master
```

and then committed with `git gui`, change-by-change, categorizing each change as "debug", "maintenance", "ticket". So the commit history looks roughly like this:

```
>> git log --oneline
1442b73 (HEAD -> devel) ticket
6d61223 ticket
011703b debug
a19067d ticket
0392f8f maintenance
af8891e ticket
b96022f maintenance
4cd9222 debug
1626927 maintenance
bda00f0 debug
971ad39 ticket
944dfde (master) bla
```

One of the "debug" commits adds debug statements, directly adjacent to dead code that is removed in a subsequent "maintenance" commit. The debug commits are not meant to be pushed to master, but I still need them locally, so I am trying to reorder this to

```
011703b (HEAD -> devel) debug
4cd9222 debug
bda00f0 debug
0392f8f maintenance
b96022f maintenance
1626927 maintenance
1442b73 ticket
6d61223 ticket
a19067d ticket
af8891e ticket
971ad39 ticket
944dfde (master) bla
```

before squashing together commits of the same topic.

```
9d76a5e (devel) debug
fd82ab3 (HEAD) ticket    <-- push up to here
b22a6f0 maintenance
f68131e (master) bla
```

During this reordering, the conflict occurs.

Comment: This is indeed normal (and annoying): adjacency counts as a conflict. [Maciej Pokrzywiński's suggestion of using `git rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234319/1256452) is probably the way to go here. I just wanted to add that I find setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` also to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know git rerere? When you enable It, he will be remember your conflict results. It can be helpful in this situation.

Good description how rerere works:

- [What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work)

You can try it in your cases and check results.