# git conflict while pull from upstream

Tags: git, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

My local `master` regularly gets several commits behind from `upstream` pulled from other feature branches.

Obviously, all **PR**s have conflicts resolved while merging to upstream. The thing is whenever I'm pulling the changes to my local, I've to face and resolve the conflicts again. But, that's already resolved while the **PR** is made. This is being a regular hassle to `pull` other's work.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: Is the section that is getting the conflict being modified _again_ by you and in the upstream branch? And, you are pulling with merge or rebase?

Comment: I'm using `merge`. No, i don't modify it again. _modified_ _again_ isn't actually issue here. I've always the same old version of `master` with upstream. While making the PR, the merge conflicts(if any) is already resolved, I don't wanna do it again.

Comment: Are you using `git rerere`? might save you from repeating conflict resolutions.

Comment: @Hasturkun No, i've not tried it yet. As i googled, It saves previous manual merge of conflicts. How can I  use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501436/20270 has information on setting it up. That answer also links information on how to train rerere on existing merge conflicts if needed. Otherwise it mostly just works automagically once enabled.