# Git rebase merge on top of new upstream

Tags: git, merge

I've finished complicated merge. During merge time upstream slightly / insignificantly moved forward.

Additionally I put extra private work before merging:

```
*   XXX (HEAD -> master) Merge 'feature' into 'master'.
|\
| * XXX (feature, origin/feature) Implementation of a feature.
* | XXX (private) Private progress on master.
| | * XXX (origin/master) New progress on master.
| |/
|/|
* | XXX (split) Point of split
```

Instead of merging `master` with `origin/master` I want to rebase `private` change + `master` merge on top of upstream `origin/master`:

```
*   XXX (HEAD -> master) Merge 'feature' into 'master'.
|\
| * XXX (feature, origin/feature) Implementation of a feature.
* | XXX (private) Private progress on master.
* | XXX (origin/master) New progress on master.
* | XXX (split) Point of split
```

The merge pointed by `master` was tough and the prior `private` change was served to simplify merge (like file renames to avoid conflicts).

`origin/master` doesn't have anything conflicting with my merge.

**How can I rebase merge** preserving all efforts I made during the merge?

Comment: I guess you need to use `git rebase -r` (a.k.a `--rebase-merges`). Check `git help rebase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in process of experimenting with the option `--rebase-merges` but documentation sates:

> Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.

As I have very troubling merge it is must simpler just to merge my merge to upstream than trying to rebase my merge on top of the upstream.

It looks like Git merging strategies during rebase cannot reuse human guided conflict resolutions...

**UPDATE** **@eftshift0** gave interesting suggestion.

There is a problem with `rerere`. It is a database of conflict resolutions. You have to fill that database:

> - Running the git rerere command **immediately after** a conflicted automerge records the conflicted working tree files
> - Later, after you are done resolving the conflicts, running git rerere again will record the resolved state of these files.

I've already merged so I missed first step...

Still managed to recreate conflict using previous resolution and with updated `rerere` database:

```
# just start from new branch to preserve entire original history
$ git checkout -b private-new private
$ git merge feature
# got conflicts, remember them!
$ git rerere
Recorded preimage for 'README.md'
# repeat conflict resolution from existing merge commit using pathspec
$ git checkout master -- README.md
# update conflict resolution database
$ git rerere
Recorded resolution for 'README.md'.
# Finish merge (and now Git remember how to resolve conflicts!)
$ git merge --continue
```

Then rebase:

- asking to preserve merge graph (`-r` or `--rebase-merges`)
- interactive (`-i`; you will see `label`, `reset`, `merge` extra language to verify or correct resulting rebase structure)
- applying merge database (`--rerere-autoupdate`) for automatic conflict resolution from the recorded resolution history.

```
$ git rebase -i -r --rerere-autoupdate origin/master
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Staged 'README.md' using previous resolution.
```

As you see you still get conflicts but they are resolved from the database.

I've got exactly desired graph (except I used alternative `private-new` branch name). Exactly the same I asked in the question.

**NOTE** `rerere` is not active by default and is a subject of GC so you might lose you database with the time passed...

**NOTE 2** Seems after activation `rerere` is applied automatically, see [What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Oh, but it can (though i don't have experience with it). `git rerere`

Answer (score 0):

Cherry pick private progress?

```
git checkout master
git branch temp
git reset --hard origin/master
git cherry-pick <private-progress-hash>
git merge feature --no-ff
```

`temp` is just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry, as I stated `git merge feature` was very complicated and I don't wont to repeat that again. I can `git merge origin/master` without a bit of hassle but I want to improve my Git mastery and keep history a little bit cleaner.