# Is there sort of a reverse cherry-pick in Git?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

**tl;dr:** How can I keep the current last couple of commits on a branch, and replace the history before that with that of another branch?

---

I have a branch where I want to keep the existing last 3 commits but replace the history with that of another branch.

So I have:

```
        E-F-G   :: my-branch
       /
A-B-C-D   :: main
  \
   B'-C'-D'     :: new-past
```

and I want

```
A-B-C-D         :: main
 \
  B'-C'-D'      :: new-past
         \
          E-F-G :: my-branch
```

Currently I am doing this manually

```
git checkout new-past
git pull
git checkout -b my-branch-temp
git checkout cherry-pick E
git checkout cherry-pick F
git checkout cherry-pick G
git branch -D my-branch
git branch -m my-branch
```

So is there some opposite of `cherry-pick` where you can insert the past commit or something or some flag on `merge` or `rebase` that would make this more elegant?

---

PS- The case here is I am on a child branch of another branch that is getting regularly rebased and I'm trying to avoid having merge commits.

PPS- I'd just as soon script the existing process were there not frequent conflicts that need to be resolved

Comment: Protip: use tools like GitKraken or SourceTree to do this kind of rebasing/cherrypicking.

Comment: `git pull` <-- Why are you doing pulls?

Comment: @Dai just to make sure I have the latest version of the code

Comment: Consider doing a `git fetch` instead: that way you'll get the remote commits added to your local repo, but without git doing any automatic fast-forwarding or merging, that way you can update your branch refs when you're ready, with fewer headaches.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly straightforward case for `git rebase --onto`, for which there's a nice example in the [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) documentation. Also, re: frequent conflicts, [`git rerere` can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501436/20270) if you're fixing the same conflicts repeatedly.

Comment: @Dai Using a Git GUI app is not "pro".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hasturkun for pointing me towards `rebase --onto` which led me to [Git `rebase --onto` an overview](https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto) & [How change parent branch in git?](https://womanonrails.com/replace-parent-branch)

So for the example in the question the answer is:

```
git rebase --onto D' D my-branch
```

Answer (score 3):

> So is there some opposite of cherry-pick where you can insert the past commit

You have the right idea, but you are over thinking it. Instead of inserting past commits, you can create a new branch and cherry-pick the commits you want on top:

```
git checkout -b new-past new-branch
git cherry-pick E
git cherry-pick F
git cherry-pick G
```

From here, you can delete the old branch and rename the new one:

```
git branch -d my-branch
git branch -m new-branch my-branch
```

For a large number of commits, this is cumbersome and time consuming Fortunately, git provides a command called `rebase` which performs batch cherry picks. It looks like this:

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase --onto new-past my-branch~3
```

Instead of `my-branch-3`, you can use any commit-ish, such as another branch, tag, or commit hash.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that behind the scenes `git rebase` does exactly the operations that OP suggested except to delete and re-create the branch, i.e., it keeps the reflog.

Comment: @j6t I was just in the middle of something along those lines.

Comment: Does that rebase formulation actually work?

Comment: @matt Do you see any reason why it shouldn't?