# Squashing some commits which are followed by merges

Tags: git, rebase

In a git repository, I have a branch in which I have regularly merged the master branch:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G (master)
 \         \              \ 
  U -- V -- M1-- X -- Y -- M2 -- Z  (feature)
```

Where the `M1` and `M2` commits merge `master` into `feature`.

I would like to squash the consecutive commits `U` and `V` and preserve the rest of the structure.

Intuitively, it should be possible to do this without having to solve the merge conflicts in `M1` and `M2` again, because by squashing `U` and `V` together I do not change the states of the working trees being merged by `M1`, nor the merge base.

However, if I do this with `git rebase -i A --rebase-merges` (with `pick U` followed by `fixup V`) I need to solve the merge conflicts of `M1` again.

Is there a way to instruct Git to re-use `M1` and the following commits as-is?

Comment: "Intuitively, it should be possible to do this without having to solve the merge conflicts in M1 and M2 again" No it shouldn't. You can't "reuse" commits. Git commits are immutable, including their parentage. So all commits after the squash, including the merge commits, must be replaced by entirely new commits constructed by Git. So the merges must be performed again. `rerere` can help with repeating the same merge conflict resolution but it probably won't help you now because you didn't turn it on. You just have to suck it up and resolve the conflicts again.

Comment: I understand that those commits will get new ids, but what I mean is that the state of the working tree in those commits should be identical to that of the corresponding commits before the rebase.

Comment: “Intuitively, it should be possible to do this without having to solve the merge conflicts in M1 and M2 again”—Conceptually yes, and `git rebase --rebase-merges` might get that capability at some point. But as it is currently implemented I think it applies the commits and doesn't care about “previous” resolutions.

Comment: Yup, and you will have to resolve any conflicts in order to construct that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500943/what-is-git-rerere-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Ideally one would use a snapshot-based rewriting tool for this since all you need to do is to create new commits with different parents: change the parent of `V` from `U` to `A` and then recalculate the transitive children. `git rebase` isn't great for this use-case (and slow anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, git is not capable of detecting that two commits to be merged happen to have the file tree in the same states as two other commits for which we already know of a merge.

Git's `rerere` tool is helpful to resolve some merge conflicts, but in my experience it can still leave some conflicts unresolved even if the merge is strictly identical to a previous merge (such as when some files were deleted on one side).

However, it is possible to force git to reuse the contents of a previous merge commit. I wrote [a small script](https://gist.github.com/wetneb/e42483ed95ffae8911ab35840fefb1a7) to help with that, to be used after the rebasing process (started with `--rebase-merges`) stopped on a conflicting merge.

If you are in a state like this:

```
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 123ab26c2a
Last commands done (123 commands done):
   pick 3baea80fd Change some files
   merge -C bb894b46f main-2 # Merge branch 'main' into feature
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
...
```

You can then call this script

```
reuse_commit bb894b46f
```

which checks that the supplied commit is a merge and that its parent commits have the same contents as the current commits to be merged (`HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD`). If those contents match, then it retrieves the contents of the merge commit and uses it to create a new merge commit (with the same metadata). You can then `git rebase --continue`.